# Multiple upload looping

Tags: php, file, loops, upload

***For some reason i have to put all input field into array.Because the input are dynamically added up to user.***

When user click on add button ,will generated the following for upload image

```
<input type="file" name="product['+n+'][gthumbnail][]"  />
```

***But i have no idea how to loop the available array(filled)***.I don't even get to count the array size.And these are my working code.Hope every expert out there can point out the mistake I did

```
//loop for image file upload
foreach($product as $productcount){

....
....
....

    //this is what i have now ,and it is not working,error saying the gthumbnail is undefined
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_FILES['gthumbnail']);$i++){

        $m=uploadFile($_FILES['gthumbnail'][$i]);

    }


}//End of product loop
```

print_r($FILES)

```
Array ( 
[product] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [thumbnail] => [gthumbnail] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) [gphoto] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) ) ) [type] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [thumbnail] => [gthumbnail] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) [gphoto] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) ) ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [thumbnail] => [gthumbnail] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) [gphoto] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) ) ) [error] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [thumbnail] => 4 [gthumbnail] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 4 [2] => 4 ) [gphoto] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 4 [2] => 4 ) ) ) [size] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [thumbnail] => 0 [gthumbnail] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 ) [gphoto] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 ) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` to see the structure.

Comment: Start by print_r($_FILES), I suspect file uploads can't be put into an array

Comment: Thanks for the print_r trick! updated question , the array look quite messy

Comment: actually, add <pre> tags to print_r() to get the output to be more understandable in a structured way. Like so: echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES); echo "</pre>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don;t you try with a single dimension array instead of `name="product['+n+'][gthumbnail][]"`. It looks like very complicated one.

may be the following will make your work easier,

```
 <form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

When the above form is submitted, the arrays `$_FILES['userfile'], $_FILES['userfile']['name']`, and `$_FILES['userfile']['size']` will be initialized.

**When register_globals is on, globals for uploaded files are also initialized. Each of these will be a numerically indexed array of the appropriate values for the submitted files.**

For instance, assume that the filenames /home/test/review.html and /home/test/xwp.out are submitted. In this case, $_FILES['userfile']['name'][0] would contain the value review.html, and $_FILES['userfile']['name'][1] would contain the value xwp.out. Similarly, $_FILES['userfile']['size'][0] would contain review.html's file size, and so forth.

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name'][0], $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][0], $_FILES['userfile']['size'][0], and $_FILES['userfile']['type'][0] are also set.
```